# Jsoup how to select a tag with multiple attributes

Tags: html, parsing, jsoup

I have  a table tag

```
<table width="100%" align="center"/>
```

And so far Jsoup provides

```
Document document =Jsoup.parse(htmlString);
document.select("table[width=100%],table[align=center]");
```

And this is OR comination i.e. if any one matches then elements are populated.
In order to select table having width =100% and align =center I have done following

```
Elements element =document.select("table[align=center]");
element =element.select("table[width=100%]");
```

So what I am asking is that just like this OR combination

```
document.select("table[width=100%],table[align=center]");
```

is there any AND combination selector i.e. table having width =100% and align =center.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can achieve an AND with one query by adding more terms to the selector. In this instance:

```
Elements tables = document.select("table[width=100%][align=center]");
```

works.

You can keep adding more terms to make it as precise as required, e.g. `table[width=100%][align=center]:contains(text)`

Comment: Yes this is the correct answer and you can look upon this on [link](https://github.com/jhy/jsoup/issues/269)

Comment: I tried this but it only trippled the results (like an OR) instead of AND `Elements appURIElements = doc.select("a[class=card-click-target][aria-hidden=true][tabindex=-1]");`

Answer (score 4):

At the moment (Jsoup 1.7.1) there no *AND* for selector available. But you can do this with two `select()`'s (like in your example #2):

```
Elements tables = document.select("table[width=100%]").select("table[align=center]");
```

You can also post a feature request: https://github.com/jhy/jsoup/issues

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply.I didn't know that this feature is available and I will surely post it as a request feature and since double select is right now the  correct way to select a tag with multiple attribute,I mark it as a correct answer for now

Comment: I mean not available instead of available

Comment: Yes, and-selector would be a nice feature.

Comment: is this **null** safe? if the first select returns **null**, there's a chance of `NullPointerException`.

Comment: Yes, ` select()` is null safe. It returns an empty `Elements` (= size of 0 `Element`'s) if nothing is selected. In case the first `select()` returns an empty result it's safe to call `select()` on this. See also: https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#select-java.lang.String-